# Javascript send Json Data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

How to send json string via ajax and convert json string to xml?

**Error:** Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
$.ajax({
                async: true,
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/btnSave",
                type: "POST",
                data: "{data: '" + "{'?xml': {'@version': '1.0'},'Card': { 'Main_Client_Information': {'Surname': '','Name': '','Middle_name': '','Full_name': '','Short_name': '','RNN': '','IIN': '','Birthday': '','Doc_Type': {'@code': ''}}}}" + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
```

if send  $.ajax data: '{data: "something"} - work perfect, how to put "**json like string**" instead "something"

**WebForm.aspx.cs**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string btnSave(string data)
    {

        string response = "";

        try
        {

            XmlDocument xmlDocument = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(data);

            xmlDocument.Save(Server.MapPath("output.xml"));

            response = "success";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response = "error" + ex.Message;
        }

        return response;

    }
```

I just want get this string ---------> "{'?xml': {'@version': '1.0'},'Card': { 'Main_Client_Information': {'Surname': '','Name': '','Middle_name': '','Full_name': '','Short_name': '','RNN': '','IIN': '','Birthday': '','Doc_Type': {'@code': ''}}}}" + "'}" ------------ in **webmethod btnSave** and convert it to xml format

Comment: Have you debugged btnSave? because your exception is being thrown then.

Comment: data is not sended to server

Comment: does the answer here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092352/relative-path-problems-in-javasvript-ajax-call

Comment: I don't think it's the cause of your problem, but your JSON string is missing a closing brace.  It should end like `{'@code': ''}}}}";`.

Comment: Why send your data as a string? if you need to build your json as a string for some reason, you could always parse it client side using `JSON.parse()` (which is supported by most browsers)

Comment: I just want get this string ----> "{'?xml': {'@version': '1.0'},'Card': { 'Main_Client_Information': {'Surname': '','Name': '','Middle_name': '','Full_name': '','Short_name': '','RNN': '','IIN': '','Birthday': '','Doc_Type': {'@code': ''}}}}" + "'}"  in **webmethod btnSave**  and convert to xml format @Timothy Groote

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies in the way you are telling jQuery which data to post :

You probably got confused, since the parameter passed on to `$.ajax` has a property named `data`.
You are now passing a string right into there, while you should be passing a Json dictionary which contains which variable names and values you want to send.

try this :

Your entire call should look something like this :

(i'm keeping the data you are trying to send in a separate variable for clarity)

```
var stringData ="{'?xml' : '@version': '1.0'},'Card': { 'Main_Client_Information': {'Surname': '','Name': '','Middle_name': '','Full_name': '','Short_name': '','RNN': '','IIN': '','Birthday': '','Doc_Type': {'@code': ''}}}}";

$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: "WebForm1.aspx/btnSave",
    type: "POST",
    data: {data:stringData},
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        debugger;
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't send the data as the json string.  You need to call JSON.parse (json_string_here_).

It is also possie that you might need put instead of post, but i cant be sure of that because i dont know if you are doing an insert or update.

Sorry, even after that ive got to say that id be a little more than impressed if you can send an xml file like that.  I would imagine that doesnt work very well.